# android- react when 2 button clicked

Tags: android, button

I want to build simple memory game. I used 16 button.
I know how to react when specific button is cliked, but how can I react to each button click and check if the match button **was selected** (not neccesrly now)?

Comment: YOu can use flags for this to remember the last value and new one.

Comment: thanks..it is good idea. And there is a way to do only 1 onclike instead of 16?

Comment: set `onClick="functionName" in xml of each button or assign them to same listener button1.setOnClickListener(this). First way is better, IMHO

Comment: if i use your first sultion, there is a way to know which button was just cliked?

Comment: Yes, posted an answer so it was more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xml, use the same name for your `onClick` for each `Button`

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btn1"
   ...
   android:onClick="btnClick"/>
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btn2"
   ...
   android:onClick="btnClick"/>
```

And in your java code make sure that the function is public, has the same name you defined in your xml's `onClick` property above, and that it takes a `View` as its only parameter. The `View` will be the `Button` clicked so you can get its `id` and `switch` on that, use `if/else` or however you want to handle that

```
public void btnClick(View v)
{
    switch(v.getId())    // v is the btn that was clicked so this will give you its id
    {
        case (R.id.btn1):   btn1 was clicked
         ... do stuff
```

To answer your first question, you can use a flag as suggested earlier or a counter and if the counter == say 2 then the click does whatever you need. If it doesn't then you store the value of what that `Button` represents to compare in the second click

the other way would be to set them in a `for loop`, I assume you know how to set up a `loop` so I will keep this short

```
for (int i=0; i<buttons.size(); i++)
{
     ...
     button[i].setOnClickListener(ActivityName.this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    int id = v.getId();
}
```

Make sure you implement `OnClickListener()`

Comment: thank. If i get each button like this:  (16 button)

 button[1]=  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1_mg);

can I ask case (v==button[i])?

Comment: If you're going to instantiate each `Button` in your code that way then use the other method and use the same `onClickListener()`. The first way I showed keeps from needing to do any of that

Comment: So I have other question. I asked this for my memory game. The words on the button are choose randomaly from an array at *tun time*.
There is a way to do it wothout  instantiate each Button?

Comment: If you are setting text at runtime then you are probably better off doing it the other way

Comment: @user1932595 I updated my answer with how you can use a single listener the other way. I just did a quick skeleton because it sounds like you know how to do the `Array` and `loop`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using logic I was able to create a program, but it's very long.
For each button you should do the same:

```
    Button B1;
    int x,y; //give them values and compare (example: B1=1, B2=2, B3=1 .. B1&B3 the same picture)
    int turn = 1; //to know whos turn (x or y), default start on x
    int numberOfClicks=0; //when 2 buttons clicked, check

    //in the OnCreate()
    B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1); //assume B1's value = 1
    B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {    //------------------------------------ OnClick Starts here

            if (turn==1){
            //use x
                x=1;
                turn=2; //flip the turn
                numberOfButtons++; //one is clicked so far
            }else{
            //use y
                y=1;
                turn=1;
                numberOfButtons++;
            }


            if(numberOfButtons==2){
            //check
                if(x==y){
                //same
                numberOfButtons=0; //restart counter
                }else{
                //not the same
                numberOfButtons=0; //restart counter
            }

        }//end of OnClick           

    }); //end of button OnClickListener
```

if B2=7, then in the OnClick, the x and y should = 7. Each OnClick will have different x and y values.