# Two buttons that do almost the same thing in one activity android

Tags: android

I am just learning android programming.

I have two activities. In my main  activity I have two buttons that do the same thing, the only difference is that one shows the result of a few calculations in the main activity and the other button passes the same result to the next activity.

I was not sure if I have to duplicate the entire code and add the intent in the second button, or there is a way not to duplicate the code.

Thanks

Marco

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528628/android-react-when-2-button-clicked/16529014#16529014) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319711/android-eclipse-which-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-button/18319759#18319759) on using `onClick` for multiple buttons. There's no need to duplicate the code. Put the identical code inside the `onClick()` and the button-specific code inside of the proper `switch/case` in the `onClick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method which calculates the result, call it from both button onClick methods and then either show the result to the user in one of the buttons, or create an intent and send it to another activity.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       int result = calculate();

       Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "" + result, Toast.SHORT).show();
   }
}); 

button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       int result = calculate();

       Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, NewActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("result", result);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

Comment: Do I have to use the onClickListener() or I can do it without?

Comment: what do you mean? You mean having in your xml for each button the onClick method name and then implement it in your activity instead of setting a OnClickListener for each? Sure.

Comment: Yes. I have two onClick methods, one each button. Is it possible to create a third method (like you showed) that can be called by the other two?

Comment: Yes, that's what his answer is showing without the actual `calculate()` method. See the links I posted in my comment above. It shows the different ways to set up an `onClick` and you can cut it down to one method if you'd like.

Comment: Basically, the simplest way I can call this method. Thanks

Comment: this is the simplest way regarding not duplicating the calculations code. The calculate() method will return the result and can be called from both button